# Any issues with replacing new Socket() with SocketChannel.open().socket()?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, socketchannel

What can go wrong if I simply replace

```
socket = new Socket()
```

with

```
socket = SocketChannel.open().socket()?
```

Background: I have some legacy code using `new Socket()`, and I wanted to be able to interrupt the `socket.connect()` call.  I don't want to rewrite the code to use NIO.  I learned that `Thread.interrupt()` does not interrupt `socket.connect()`, but that `socket.close()` on another thread is supposed to interrupt the connection.  Oddly, that worked with Java 7 but not Java 6.

I somehow got it into my head that using `socket = SocketChannel().open().socket()` would magically allow me to use `Thread.interrupt()` to interrupt `socket.connect()`.  It doesn't, but oddly, it does make `socket.close()` interrupt `socket.connect()` in Java 6 too!

Note that I'm not directly using the attached `SocketChannel` in any way---it appears when I create the `Socket` and never again.

What can go wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

There are several.

1. A Socket acquired via a SocketChannel doesn't appear to support read timeouts.
2. The InputStream and OutputStream of a socket aren't independent: they have a mutual lock in common.

Why do you want to interrupt the connect() call? Surely all you want is a connect timeout?

Comment: (2) is not an issue as this is a request/response protocol.  I'll investigate (1).  I want to interrupt the `connect()` for [Happy Eyeballs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Eyeballs): one thread is trying IPv6 and a second thread is trying IPv4, and if IPv6 is broken such that `connect()` will time out, I want to interrupt that `connect()` as soon as the IPv4 connection is made.

Comment: In that case you would be better off connecting the channels in non-blocking mode and closing the one that fires OP_CONNECT second.

Comment: I think I agree, but I was hoping to avoid the work of reconfiguring the code for NIO.  But maybe I can configure back to blocking after a successful connect and just work with the socket streams after that?  Can you (or someone) show the code that would replace `socket = SocketChannel.open().socket(); socket.connect(address, timeout);`?

Comment: My testing indicates that `socket.setSoTimeout()` works just fine on a Socket acquired via a SocketChannel, causing the expected `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` to be thrown while blocking on `socket.getInputStream().read()`.

Comment: Bizarre. I've seen a Sun bug report indicating the contrary. It's cited somewhere on this site.

Comment: Well, there's [this](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4614802), but it is a not-a-bug about `socketChannel.read()` not respecting the timeout.  As the bug evaluation mentions, `socketChannel.socket().getInputStream().read()` times out just fine.

Comment: Could you please expand on (2) as to where the mutual lock is?  Does it mean `OutputStream.write()` will block if called while another thread is blocked in `InputStream.read()`?

Comment: n/m, found the appropriate links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174774/java-are-concurrent-reads-and-writes-possible-on-a-blocking-socketchannel-via-o and http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=d76c6fabad9827be488fceb8d9f4?bug_id=4509080

Answer (score 0):

Differences in the type of thrown exceptions could break existing code.

For instance, closing a `Socket` from a different thread while `Socket.getInputStream().read()` is blocking will result in [AsynchronousCloseException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousCloseException.html) after replacing, instead of `SocketException` that legacy code could be expecting. (`AsynchronousCloseException` is not a subclass of `SocketException`.)

However, `Socket.getInputStream().read()` will still throw `SocketException` if the close from the other thread gets in before `read()`.