# Socket vs SocketChannel.open().socket()

Tags: java, sockets, java-8, nio

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a `Channel` backed `Socket`, obtained via `SocketChannel.open().socket()`, over a traditional `Socket` obtained from `new Socket()`?

A similar question three years ago ([Any issues with replacing new Socket() with SocketChannel.open().socket()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775628/any-issues-with-replacing-new-socket-with-socketchannel-open-socket)) touches on this, but much of its information looks outdated. (Tested in Java 8)

My research has found these advantages/disadvantages:

#### Advantages over `new Socket()`

- Reads on the socket's `InputStream` can be interrupted with `Thread.interrupt()`, which subsequently also closes the socket and throws `ClosedByInterruptionException`.  Although it's unfortunate that it closes the socket, I'd have to close it anyway to break out of reads on `new Socket()` and I'd have to separately keep track the socket a thread is bound to.
- Likewise, `Socket.connect()` can be interrupted with `Thread.interrupt()`, which also results in `ClosedByInterruptionException`.
- Calling `Socket.close()` during `Socket.connect()` results in `AsynchronousCloseException`, unlike the cryptic `SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect` I get for `new Socket()`.

#### Advantages over `SocketChannel`

- Reads can be timed out with `Socket.setSoTimeout()`.
- Can be wrapped in `SSLSocket` (with `SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket, ...)`) to do a quick SSL/TLS transition.

#### Disadvantages over `SocketChannel`

- Doesn't gain the advantages of using `ByteBuf` to reduce copying during reads or writes, so maybe slower in this sense.

#### Disadvantages over `new Socket()`

- ???

Comment: There is no outdated information in the duplicate.